# Are MS Excel's built-in conditional functions computationally more efficient than array calculations using standard operators?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, processing-efficiency

The question essentially is whether built-in conditional functions in Excel such as `SUMIF()`, `COUNTIF()`, `AVERAGEIF()` but also `SUBTOTAL()` and `AGGREGATE()` are computationally more efficient, i.e. lighter, than using their unconditional variants (`SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc.) in combination with array calculations and simple operators (`*`, `+`, ...).

Moreover, can this even be answered generally or does it depend on further factors such as the class (string vs numeric)?

An example should make things clearer. Suppose we have the following table, where the data ranges in columns B, C and D are named 'CriteriaRange1', 'CriteriaRange2', and 'ValueRange', respectively:

[image: Example Table]

The formula used in H8 is `=SUMIFS(ValueRange,CriteriaRange1,"="&H3,CriteriaRange2,">"&H4)`, i.e. using the built-in `SUMIFS()` function

and the formula used in H9 is `=SUM(ValueRange*(CriteriaRange1=H3)*(CriteriaRange2>H4))`, i.e. using the unconditional `SUM()` function in combination with array multiplication.

Can it be generally said that one is computationally more efficient. And if not, does it depend on the value class, e.g. string vs numeric as represented by 'Criteria Range 1' and 'Criteria Range 2' in the example above. Or can it just not be generalized that easily at all?

**Edit 1:**

I created an example sheet and copied the microtimer function for more precise timing of calculations from this [Webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance#measuring-calculation-time). On this example sheet I timed the calculation times of the built-in functions `SUMIF()`, `AVERAGEIF()` and `COUNTIF()` against the array versions for the same task, e.g. `SUM(X*(X>Y))`. Exact functions used shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu22c.png).

The results were the following:

[image: Empirical Analysis]

For the functions tested, it is pretty safe to say that the built-in versions were consistently more efficient than array calculations from a limited empirical perspective. Moreover, it seems the calculation times of the built-in functions vary significantly less across the functions than for the array counterparts.

It would still be great to get an answer from someone who is familiar with computation methodology deployed by Excel to explain this in a more generalized manner.

Comment: Build both versions with a large data set and time the processes. I used to run macros overnight - efficiency was great if the results were available for 8AM…

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about doing that today. But that would be an empirical test that only allows for specific but not general conclusions. Good starting point though. I was hoping that someone is familiar with the actual methodology of Excels computations and can answer the question in general.

Comment: There's no such thing as a general conclusion here, since any conclusion you do draw might easily be invalidated in the next version of Excel. Or, indeed, a previous one if your end users happen to be running that. Or Google Sheets if some enterprising soul decides to port it there. From a theoretical perspective the best you could say is that both approaches will run in time linear to the number of items involved, which isn't saying much.